# iOS Facebook SDK - Some info

Tags: ios, facebook, feed

i get the facebook news feed from the `requestGraphWithPath:andDelegate` method. All ok, but one things isn't clear : how can i get the user's profile photo that post the feed? Every news has link, date, description, but i cannot find link to user's profile photo.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each wall post you have a "from" field with "id" field. This is the id of the user who made the post, then you simply add "picture" suffix to that graph object to get their profile picture, example:
https://graph.facebook.com/ID/picture

hope this helps